# How to insert html page saved in a folder using href in Python script

Tags: python, html

Re-editing question:

so currently I have

```
imagepath = os.join.path (currentdirectory, fruit, size, fruitproperty + ".html")
```

Now I want to insert this path into following code:

```
htmlfile.write('<a href = imagepath > '+fruitproperty+' </a><br>\n')
```

so my problem is how to insert the imagepath in it? I have tried various ways, but not working.

Comment: Does your script reside in currentdirectory? or its parent?

Comment: currentdirectory is where I run the script. I get the path as currentdirectory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `string.format` , example -

```
imagepath = os.join.path (currentdirectory, fruit, size, fruitproperty + ".html")
htmlfile.write(('<a href = {imagepath} > '+fruitproperty+' </a><br>\n').format(imagepath = imagepath))
```

Here , the `imagepath` inside the `{}` (curly brackets) would be substituted with the value for imagepath.